# WordPress MU and nested sites addresses?

Tags: multisite

I'm creating my first path-based WordPress Multisite Network. Right now it runs a few blogs, such as:

```
www.mymaindomain.com
www.mymaindomain.com/blog1
www.mymaindomain.com/blog2
www.mymaindomain.com/blog3
```

I'm wondering is it possible to change my blogs URLs to something like:

```
www.mymaindomain.com
www.mymaindomain.com/directory/blog1
www.mymaindomain.com/directory/blog2
www.mymaindomain.com/directory/blog3
```

It's quite tricky to achieve with .htaccess as I have absolutely no idea how to tell the difference between sites such as `www.mymaindomain.com/blog1` and pages like `www.mymaindomain.com/contactpage`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it could be solved within your [permalink settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#Permalinks). Go to the respective sites settings and add it to your permalink structure.